# How to show different progress bars for EACH file being uploaded through ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, progress-bar

First off, thanks for your time, secondly, please read the tittle again....I'm not requesting help for a simple progress bar since there's plenty of documentation for it on the internet but for multiple progress bars in the same request... of which seems not to be any tutorial about it.

I don't want plugins for this, I'm trying to do it by my own....with your help :D and I think we might be able to get it done without plugins

what do you need to do to get multiple progress bar of the files being send through an Ajax request? I almost got it but I haven't been able to figure out what to do to next to discriminate each event and show their progress. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="upload_pics">Upload+</div>
<ul id="here">
</ul>
```

and here the JS:

```
function readURL() {
        if(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob){
            //All the File APIs are supported.
        }else{
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser, try to update it or get a new one here.');
            }
        }

    function handlefiles(event){
        var files = event.target.files;
        var i,f;

        var form_data = new FormData(); 
        for(var i = 0; f=files[i];i++){
            form_data.append(i,f);
            if(!f.type.match('image.*')){
                continue;   
            }

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function(the_file){
                return function(e){
                    var li = $("<li/>").attr('class','thumbnailupic');

                    li.html('<img class="thumb" src="'+e.target.result+'" title="'+ the_file.name+ '"/><div class="progress_bar"><div class="percent"></div></div><div class="cancel_read" title="remove">x</div>');

                    li.appendTo($("#here"));

                };
            })(f);

            $("#start_upload").click(function(e) {  
            $.ajax({
                xhr: function() {
                    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();          
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                            var percentComplete = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);

                            // this shows me the progress of each file being uploaded 
                            console.log(percentComplete);

                            if(percentComplete){
                                if(percentComplete <= 100){
                                    //I want each "li" that is automatically generated containing their respective progress par being filled up as the upload happens but I'm stuck....since I don't know how


                                    //this is what i had in mind.... I was thinking about looping but it's useless since I don't know how to go to the next element after the first file it's sent....
                                    //$("#here li:eq("+i+")").find('.percent').css({"width":"" + percentComplete + '%' + "",'height':'100%','background-color':'#906'});
                                }


                            }

                        }
                   }, false);

                   return xhr;
                },
                type: 'POST',
                url: "process_upload.php",
                data: form_data,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false, 
                processData: false,
                success: function(data){
                    //Do something on success
                }
            });

            });

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }

    $("#upload_pics").click(function(e) {
        if($("#start_upload").length == 0){
            var start_upload = $("<div/>").attr('id','start_upload').html("start upload");
            start_upload.insertAfter($(this));
        }
        if($("#upics").length == 0){
            $("<input>").prop({"type":"file","multiple":true,"id":"upics","name":"pics[]"}).trigger('click').change(function(e) {
                readURL();  
            },handlefiles);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, you can only get progress updates on the content of the request as a whole. You could send each file in its own request, but that would potentially cause server load problems, and isn't a good idea just to get separate progress bars to work

Comment: Try https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coding everything in the body of the document, wrap each instance into its own object.  Get the functionality correct in a single object then you can create as many instances of the object as you wish and it will work.